# How can I identify if the chart exists in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

The code I am running opens up a workbook and copies a chart from it and pastes it into a PowerPoint slide. Following this, it will open up another workbook of apparently identical format, copy a chart and similarly paste it into PowerPoint.

**The issue**: The first graph is successfully copied and pasted into PowerPoint, however when I open up the second workbook and set it to the active workbook there is an issue with running the following code:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Charts("Chart1").ChartArea.Copy
```

I get the error: 
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range.

I have checked the opened workbook and there is a graph within it. I think the issue may be that the graph in the second workbook may not be named "Chart1" however I am not sure how to find this out.

Comment: Have you tried referring to the chart by its number instead of its name? `ActiveWorkbook.Charts(1).ChartArea.Copy`

Comment: Hi Abdallah, I just tried that and it worked! Thank you

Comment: You will get `Subscript out of range` in your case if there is a typo in the name of the chart. Using chart number is only safe if there is only 1 chart in the file. I would still recommend avoiding using index numbers in charts, sheets etc... I would recommend naming your charts and using that name in the code. For example name your chart `SalesFigures` if it shows sales figures. You can name your chart by selecting the chart and typing the name in the name box. [**Note**: This is just my opinion and may differ from what others prefer]